# I need to update MySQL database through Jenkins

Tags: mysql, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

if i run a pipeline in jenkins, once it completed the database table should update yes if its sucessfully completed,and it will trigger next job vice versa, im using windows os, not getting rightfull resources get that command

this command works well to connect database "bat 'mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u root -pdemopassword -e "USE databasename; show tables;"' but for writing many queries it will ask each time, so i try to configure through environment, but it failed, i pluged in mysql databse plugin, it collect my details in global database configuration and the test connection also success but i cant use it in the pipeline, please somebody write some suggestions

Comment: ou can send a sql fule to msql that it will process without an further interaction, but ou must be certain that all is in order

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to achieve this would be to use a programming language you know well and make a program that makes those queries, instead of trying to do it directly from the shell.

We usually make our scripts outside of Jenkins and call those scripts from Jenkins it gives you more flexibility.

Since you're on Windows if you don't want to install another language you can `Install-Module MySQLCmdlets` and use PowerShell.

If you're more confortable using Python, Java, javascript or any other languages, most languages have a module to connect to MySQL.

---

*Edit*
Steps to run a Java script on Jenkins :

1. If it's not already done, Install Java on the machine running Jenkins.
2. Write your program in Java, compile it with javac and make a jar file out of it (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html)
3. In your Jenkins Project add a build step with Batch script
4. From a batch script, you can run a .jar `java -jar <your_jar_file_name>.jar` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/run.html)

Comment: sorry to ask this qus, im newbie to jenkins, inside jenkins only groovy language will work right, how do I use java as code? having confusion about this, how it will work?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).